# UIImageView image in LaunchScreen.storyboard does not appear. How to fix this?

Tags: ios, xcode, launch-screen

I have a LaunchScreen.storyboard that opens up and shows an image at startup. However, recently I needeed to change this image to something else.

The problem is this new image does not appear on some of the devices. What could be the problem here?

I tried restarting the device, xcode, my mac and everything.
I tried setting "clears graphics context" of imageview.

Comment: Try to add images inside project instead of Assets.xcassets

Comment: may constraint you give with Specific size class. remove all constraint and give again with size class with any: any

Comment: Tried adding the image inside the project. Results were incostistent again. In some devices it worked in some it didnt.

Comment: Is this happening after you've published the app, and users install the upgraded version? Or is this just when running from Xcode? If from Xcode, make sure you delete the app from the device and *then* run the new version.

Comment: This happened both on when running from Xcode and after publishing with Testflight.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen. Assuming you are still displaying the "old" image, try deleting the app, restarting the device (this may not be needed), then re-installing the app. That cleared things up for me.

(If you are talking about the simulator, you also have the option to "Reset Content and Settings".)